# How to use copy elision when function is called in if block

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, c++17, copy-elision

In the following snippet, no move and no copy of `A` happens thanks to copy elision

```cpp
struct A;
A function1();
A function2();

int main(int argc, char**) {
  if (argc > 3) {
    A a = function1();
  } else {
    A a = function2();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This is nice, however `a` is not accessible outside the if-block. When declaring `a` outside, then a move happens

```cpp
struct A;
A function1();
A function2();

int main(int argc, char**) {
  A a;
  if (argc > 3) {
    a = function1();
  } else {
    a = function2();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

What is a recommendable attern to profit from copy elision when it should happen in an if block on the call site into a variable outside the if scope?

[Compiler-Exlorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/48kyNh)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Immediately-Invoked Lambda Expression (IILE) can save the day in this and more complicated cases:

```
A a = [&] {
  if (…) {
    return function1();
  } else {
    return function2();
  }
}();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even more complicated scenarios like `if(...) { A a; doSomething(); return a; } else ...` don't get advantage of mandatory copy elision. Moreover, GCC (up to at least 10.1) doesn't even do voluntary copy elision: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fGrPUJ (although Clang does, even in version 6.0)

Comment: FWIW, I've reported this to GCC: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96065

Comment: Hopefully, this problem will be gone in C++23: http://wg21.link/p2025

Answer (score 7):

In this particular case you can use the ternary conditional:

```
A a = argc>3 ? function1() : function2();
```

In more complicated cases you may need to save the condition and do several checks, e.g.

```
const bool cond = argc>3;
A a = cond ? function1() : function2();
A b = cond ? function3() : function4();
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, you have to use **placement new** to use prvalues (“mandatory copy elision”, which is not copy elision) in **arbitrary** contexts (*e.g.*, with statements or with reuse of variables).  You then also have the responsibility to call the **destructor** manually; the safe and clean way to do that is to write a helper class:

```
template<class T>
struct box {
  char buf[sizeof(T)];  // real code should handle alignment
  T *p{};  // will point to buf
  void reset() {
    if(p) p->~T();
    p=nullptr;
  }
  ~box() {reset();}
};

void f() {
  box<A> a;
  if(…) a.p=new (a.buf) A(function1());
  else a.p=new (a.buf) A(function2());
  // use *a.p
}
```

Of course, `box` is just a reimplementation of `std::optional` with the guts exposed.  It’s unfortunate that you have to assign to `box::p` **externally**, but wrapping the `new` in a function would of course **materialize** a temporary for the `A` returned from whatever function.  (Having `box::p` be a pointer rather than just a flag avoids having to use `std::launder` to deal with **lifetime** issues.)

Comment: If you're going to advocate placement `new`, you might want to add a note about cleanup (i.e., manually calling the dtor).

Comment: @StephenNewell: I did better than that: I provided a destructor for `box` that does so because I couldn’t stand to write exception-unsafe code that did it manually (or an ugly `catch(...)`).

Comment: Yes, but I think an explanation as to why you're manually calling the dtor is useful.  I've found this is a major point of confusion since a stunning number of a C++ developers haven't used placement new and think it's never correct to manually call a dtor.

Comment: @StephenNewell: Fair enough: I’ll edit in some admonishment.

Comment: @StephenNewell I hope most C++ developers aren't using placement new. As ugly as it is, replacing all your ifs with ternaries or IILE is 100x better than this.